# Загрузка файла вызовом стороннего приложения

Tags: java, android

**Дано:**

1. Сервер с файлом
2. Приложение с правами на интернет, запись и чтение

**Задача:**

Скачать файл с помощью стандартных средств и/или сторонних приложений. 
Пояснение: хочется послать некий **Intent** коий выдаст **Chooser**, в коем можно выбрать каким приложением загрузить файл. Беглое гугленье не помогло(

**P.S.** Файл - песенка (*.mp3). Его я могу с сервера проиграть, скачать сам программно, а хочется дать юзеру возможность привычными средствами его скачать и поместить куда угодно. Например у меня на девайсе есть ES-Manager, коий появляется в списке приложений для скачивания файлов и можно качать им.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все довольно просто:

```
String url = "http://your-site.com/your-file.mp3";
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(i);
```

Это откроет пикер (если не задано действие поумолчанию), в котором будут присутствовать все браузеры, а так же все менеджеры загрузок (если они сделаны правильно). К примеру, `ES Downloader` присутствует

Comment: Да, действительно просто) Спасибо!